# How can Julia shell commands handle pipes?

Tags: shell, julia, read-eval-print-loop

Using shell commands from within the Julia 1.0 REPL.   `; ls` works fine, so does `;sort foo`

However, I've had no success with pipes, `; ls| sort`

`shell> ls | sort 
ls: sort: No such file or directory
ls: |: No such file or directory`

Any workarounds?  I'm running bash on macos.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/#Pipelines-1), you need to use `run` and `pipeline`:

Try running:

```
run(pipeline(`ls`, `sort`))
```

Comment: or `run(\`ls\` |> \`sort\`)`

Comment: i'm using 1.0 macos  @user1934428
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Cmd are not callable
Stacktrace:
 [1] |>(::Cmd, ::Cmd) at ./operators.jl:813
 [2] top-level scope at none:0`

Comment: @niczky12 `run(pipeline...))`. works, but it doesnt have the same feel as ";"

Comment: I know. But this is the only workaround I could find. Have you tried asking on slack?